# Outlook Add-in REST API read mail EML "ErrorAccessDenied"

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi

I'm using the Outlook REST API to load the contents of the selected mail inside an Office.js Outlook Add-in. All works great, but now one tenant reports an issue which was triggered by the request below.

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{mail id}/$value
```

It returns the status code 403 with the following response body.

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

But the weird thing about that is, when I call the route below, with exactly the same token, it works without any problems.

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{mail id}?$select=subject,body
```

The access token is sent with each request inside the "Authorization" header which was created by the Office.js library's 'getCallbackTokenAsync' function. I think this might have something to do with the tenants configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were having having trouble with exactly the same scenario. We had this route:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{mail id}/$value
```

being used in our production product. It was working for many months. Early this week we started to receive reports of users receiving the 403 error on access to the /$value route.

It is still working for some users, but they have found that after running windows update the issue begins for them also.

We have identified that the security requirements for this call have been increased. In order to allow access you will need to increase the required permission levels defined in your Add-in manifest to ReadWriteMailbox (we previously had ReadWriteItem).

```
<OfficeApp ...>
    ...
    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
    ...
</OfficeApp>
```

Not ideal, but a solution none-the-less. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission

Comment: We were having the same issue (was working and then it stopped) and I changed the permissions from ReadWriteItem to ReadWriteMailbox as suggested and now it is working. The odd thing was that I was running this on mobile and it was working for iOS but not Android.